# In Python, how is a multiple replace possible without translating individual characters?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to translate multiple strings using a dictionary; however, it always replaces each individual character, and I don't know how to tweak my code.

My dictionary:

```
{"You're": "I'm", "We've": "you've", 'am': 'are', "We'll": "you'll", 'im': "you're",
"we'd": "you'd", 'our': 'your', 'You': 'I', 'Was': 'were', 'your': 'my', "you're":
"I'm", 'We': 'you', "I've": "you've", "we've": "you've", 'This': 'that', "we're":
"you're", 'you': 'I', 'was': 'were', 'me': 'you', 'we': 'you', 'I': 'you', 'c': 'see',
"I'd": "you'd", 'Were': 'was', "I'm": "you're", 'My': 'your', "I'll": "you'll", "we'll":
"you'll", 'this': 'that', 'Am': 'are', 'ur': "I'm", 'i': 'you', 'u': 'me', "We'd":
"you'd", 'were': 'was', 'Our': 'your', "i'm": "you're", 'my': 'your', 'Your': 'my',
"We're": "you're"}
```

My code:

```
def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.iteritems():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text
```

Which is called later by:

```
message = replace_all(message, dictionary)
```

Is it possible to replace entire words in strings? I'm very new to python, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Blender's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15856698) works just fine if none of your replacements overlap, but if you've got replacements like this (which you do):

```
{'I': 'you', 'you': 'I'}
```

Then the previous replacements get replaced again, which is undesirable. A small extension of his answer fixes that:

```
import re

def replace_all(text, dic):
    words = sorted(dic, key=len, reverse=True)
    return re.sub('\\b(' + '|'.join(map(re.escape, words)) + ')\\b',
                  lambda m: dic[m.group(0)], text)
```

This works by first creating a regular expression that looks like this:

```
\b(you|I)\b
```

As described in [the `re` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax), `\b` stands for "word boundary"<sup>1</sup>. As such, it'll only match the inner part on word boundaries. The `|` denotes multiple choices within the parenthesized portion of the regular expression. It's necessary to reverse-sort the choices on length because Python will stop as soon as the first one matches; if `I` was before, say, `I'm`, then it would never match `I'm` because `I` always matches before `I'm`.

So we're passing that regular expression to [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub), which can take as a replacement not only a replacement string but alternatively a *function*, which allows for more complex logic. Our function looks up the text we matched in the dictionary and returns the value associated with that key as the text to replace with.

<sup>1</sup> Unfortunately, the definition of 'word' is not intelligent when it comes to parentheses, so:

```
>>> replace_all("I'm not convinced.", {"I": "you"})
"you'm not convinced."
```

Fortunately, because we sorted it, the longest match will always happen first:

```
>>> replace_all("I'm not convinced.", {"I": "you", "I'm": "you're"})
"you're not convinced."
```

Comment: It's definitely an improvement! However, it still seems to translate mid-word. For example, the expected result for a test was "You think I'm just a machine?" and it returns "You thyounk i'm jmest a maseehyoune?"

Comment: @ShaunGillies: Oh gosh, you're right. I forgot some parentheses. Try it now, although it still might have a problem with apostrophes…

Comment: That's it! Thank you! If it's not too much trouble, could you quickly explain what's going on in the code, though? I don't want to come up against this wall again because I won't have actual knowledge of the code.

Comment: @ShaunGillies: Sure! I've added a little explanation to my answer.

Comment: @ShaunGillies: On refining my explanation, I've found a little bug. It's fixed in the latest edit of my answer.

Comment: This was absolutely it. I'm still having an issue with some message returns, but I'll iron out that bug. Thank you so much for your help!